# How to set up a development environment using git for my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, git, version-control, bitbucket

I am developing a wordpress website and it is live. I am currently using file-zilla to update my code. Until now I wasn't in need of any version control, but now it seems that I need to manage a repository as well. We have also added two freelancers in a development team. So, it becomes difficult for us to manage development of this website.

I have read several blogs and I came to a decision that I will use Git for version control. However, I am struggling to find proper steps which explain to me about setting up a development environment for a team of freelancers. Also, I got a little information about bitbucket, but I am not sure if that is necessary for me. I am looking for the best answer to get started.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you are leaving core Wordpress files alone and working only with themes and / or plugins as is best practice:)

Create a git repository every theme and plugin that you are working on using a server of your choice: I would go with Bitbucket for free private repos that you can invite the devs to.

Since you already have the files pushed by FileZilla, you would go into each of the folders for the themes and plugins you are using and push them as existing repos using SSH like so:

First initilize the repos and commit:

```
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -a -m "initial commit"
```

Then push

```
$git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:my_org/my_repo.git
$git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
$git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

If you are editing core files as well which would be highly discouraged, then you would create just one repo for the entire Wordpress folder, and then initialize, add, commit and push as above.

Development environments would be set up by the devs themselves using the platforms of their choice. Or ask them to use [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) if you want them to have similar environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to your suggestion I have installed Git on my local. I have pushed my local theme repository on bitbucket, and I am using Source Tree client to push all commits to bitbucket. But, after committing on bitbucket, I still have to upload file via FTP to reflect changes which make on my local to my main site. I think, it double up my work. Can I directly install git on my server and push master repository to bitbucket? I think SSH wil help, but I don't know how to do it. Also I don't have idea about setting up development environment for freelancers.

Comment: You should check if your host provides SSH access. Some don't.